# HTML page can't get angularjs http response data, but the data is not null

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my first post here and pardon me if I violate any forum rule that I didn't know of. I did tried to search about this particular issue countless time but doesn't find what I need.

The question is my html page I wrote it with bootstrap elements in it cannot get data from the controller when using the ng-repeat attribute. This code generate the content only when I spam the search button twice or three times, it never succeed gotten the data the first time I click on it. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid home row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="padding: 1em 2em">
        <form ng-submit="searchBookings()">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2" >
                <md-input-container>
                    <md-select ng-model="numBed" placeholder="Number of Beds">
                        <md-option>1</md-option>
                        <md-option>2</md-option>
                        <md-option>3</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <md-input-container>
                    <md-select ng-model="kitchen" placeholder="Kitchen">
                        <md-option>No</md-option>
                        <md-option>Yes</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <md-input-container>

                    <md-select ng-model="roomType" placeholder="Room Type">
                        <md-option>Single Suite</md-option>
                        <md-option>Double Suite</md-option>
                        <md-option>Honeymoon Suite</md-option>
                        <md-option>Presidential Suite</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <md-input-container>
                    <md-select ng-model="view" placeholder="View">
                        <md-option>Skyline</md-option>
                        <md-option>Beachfront</md-option>
                        <md-option>Courtyard</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>

            <div id="pricePerNight" class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="labelAlign">
                    <p style="display: inline;  margin-bottom: 20px" id="priceLbl">PRICE (${{ price }})</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <md-slider-container>
                        <md-slider class="md-primary" flex min="0" max="3000" ng-model="price" aria-label="price" id="price-slider"></md-slider>    
                    </md-slider-container>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="startDate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="endDate">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div><p style="padding-bottom: 1.5em"> </p></div>
        </form>  
    </div>

    <!--
    <p>{{rooms.array}}</p>
    -->
    <!-- test code -->
    <div class="container-fluid row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div ng-repeat="room in rooms.array">
                <p>Room number: {{room.id}}</p>
                <p>Room Type: {{room.roomType}}</p>
                <p>Beds: {{room.numBed}}</p>
                <p>Kitchen: {{room.kitchen}}</p>
                <p>View: {{room.view}}</p>
                <p>$: {{room.pricePerNight}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" ng-cloak>
            <caption ng-if="">Number of rooms {{ rooms.array.length }}</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Room Number</th>
                    <th>Room Type</th>
                    <th>Beds</th>
                    <th>Kitchen</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>Price Per Night</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="room in rooms.array">
                    <td>{{ room.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ room.roomType }}</td>
                    <td>{{ room.numBed }}</td>
                    <td>{{ room.kitchen }}</td>
                    <td>{{ room.view }}</td>
                    <td>{{ room.pricePerNight }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the controller

```
 app.controller('bookingController', ['$resource', '$log', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$mdSidenav', '$q', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function ($resource, $log, $rootScope, $scope, $mdSidenav, $q, $http, $location, $cookies) {
    $scope.price = 500;
    $scope.startDate = '';
    $scope.endDate = '';
    $scope.roomType = '';
    $scope.numBed = 1;
    $scope.kitchen = '';
    $scope.view = '';
    var changed =  false;
    $scope.rooms = {
        array: []
    };
    var data = [];
    $scope.error;
    $scope.searchBookings = function () {
        if ($scope.kitchen === 'Yes') {
            $scope.kitchen = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.kitchen = 0;
        }

        $location.search({
            roomType: $scope.roomType || ['Single Suite', 'Double Suite', 'Economy Suite', 'Presidential Suite', 'Honeymoon Suite']
            , pricePerNight: $scope.price || 5000
            , kitchen: $scope.kitchen || [0, 1]
            , view: $scope.view || ['Courtyard', 'Skyline', 'Beachfront']
            , numBed: $scope.numBed || [1, 2, 3]
        });


        var Rooms =  $resource('/bookings/?', $location.search(), {
            query: {
                method: 'GET'
                , isArray: true
                , headers: {
                    Auth: $cookies.get('Auth')
                }
            }
        });

        /*request($location.url())*/
        /*$http(req)*/
        Rooms.query().$promise.then(function (result) {
            data = result;
            $scope.error = null;
            changed = true;
            $log.debug('Value of changed: ' + changed);
            $log.debug('Result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            //$scope.rooms.array = result;
            //$scope.$apply();
            //$log.info('Success: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.rooms.array));
            $log.info('Num rooms: ' + data.length);
            $scope.$watch(changed, function () {

                    $log.debug('WE CHANGED ROOMS ARRAY');
                    $scope.rooms.array = data;
                    $log.debug('ROOMS ARR: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.rooms.array));

            });
        }, function (err) {
            $scope.error = err.data.error;
            //$log.error('Error retrieving bookings: ' + JSON.stringify(err.data));
        });  
    };
}]);
```

HTML page have a search bar that have drop down menu and slider to search for items. I have problem with the ng-repeat for table on the bottom of the html page.

If anyone have any tips on this please let me know. Thank you!

Data to the rooms.array

```
Result: [{"id":4,"roomType":"Single Suite","pricePerNight":299.99,"view":"Courtyard","kitchen":1,"numBed":1},{"id":5,"roomType":"Single Suite","pricePerNight":499.99,"view":"Skyline","kitchen":0,"numBed":1},{"id":8,"roomType":"Single Suite","pricePerNight":399.99,"view":"Skyline","kitchen":0,"numBed":1},{"id":10,"roomType":"Economy Suite","pricePerNight":99.99,"view":"Courtyard","kitchen":0,"numBed":1}]
```

Comment: post the data you get in rooms.array

Comment: I just added the data content of the rooms.array to the bottom of the original post of the page.